# If we know $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$, does it mean $\gcd\left(\frac{a}{\gcd\left(a,b\right)},\gcd\left(c,\frac{b}{\gcd\left(a,b\right)}\right)\right)=1$

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

If we know $gcd(a,b,c)=1$, how to prove that $gcd\left(\frac{a}{gcd\left(a,b\right)},gcd\left(c,\frac{b}{gcd\left(a,b\right)}\right)\right)=1$? Where $a, b, c$ are any positive integers.

I have test two specific examples, looks it is true:

Example 1):
Such as when $a=35,b=55,c=77\Longrightarrow\ gcd(35,55,77)=1$, we have
$gcd\left(\frac{35}{gcd\left(35,55\right)},gcd\left(77,\frac{55}{gcd\left(35,55\right)}\right)\right)=gcd\left(7,gcd\left(77,11\right)\right)=gcd(7,11)=1$

Example 2):
Such as when $a=3,b=5,c=7\Longrightarrow\ gcd(3,5,7)=1$, we have
$gcd\left(\frac{3}{gcd\left(3,5\right)},gcd\left(7,\frac{5}{gcd\left(3,5\right)}\right)\right)=gcd\left(3,gcd\left(7,1\right)\right)=gcd(3,1)=1$

Comment: it is good practice to show your own efforts and get answer

Comment: By the linked dupes $\,d=(a,b) \Rightarrow (a/d,(c,b/d)) = ((a/d,b/d),c) = (1,c)=1\ \ $

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We are gonna use these two facts: $gcd(x,gcd(y,z)) = gcd(gcd(x,y),z) = gcd(x,y,z)$ and for every positive integer w, $gcd(w*x,w*y) = w*gcd(x,y)$

Let $g = gcd(a,b)$

$g * gcd(a/g,b/g) = gcd(g * a/g,g * b/g) = gcd (a,b) = g$

Cancelling g from both sides, $gcd(a/g,b/g)=1$

Let $k = gcd(a/g , gcd(c , b/g))$

$k = gcd(a/g , gcd(b/g , c)) = gcd( gcd(a/g,b/g), c)) = gcd( 1, c) = 1$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: Further, please do not duplicate prior-posted answers on this page.

Comment: I didn't duplicate any prior-posted answers on this page. I only saw the other answer after I finished writing mine, and the two answers should have been written a few minutes apart if you would check that @BillDubuque

Comment: The other answer was posted 20 minutes prior, not "a few minutes apart".

Comment: That's a few minutes apart by my standards. Point is that the question was unanswered on my screen at the time I posted my answer, until the page reloaded. Not sure if there is any benefit from arguing about that

Comment: If you take a long time after loading the page before posting an answer then you should always refresh the page to avoid posting duplicate answers.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep that in mind next time